# why doesn't useQuery 'skip' option accept my boolean?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

**What i'm trying to do:** skip the query if the parameter in the query doesn't change.

I understand that useQuery is smart enough to not run if the input parameter doesn't change. However, if I have useQuery in componentA, and i switch from it to componentB and back to componentA, useQuery will run again even if the input parameter is the same.

So, I thought of using the skip option in useQuery. However its behaviour is not as expected. If I define a constant that is a boolean outside and set it to the 'skip' option, the query isn't skipped even if my constant was 'true'.

```js
    const skipQuery = props.match.params.itineraryId == placeState.itineraryId;
    console.log(skipQuery) // prints true
    const { data } = useQuery(GET_ITINERARY, {
        skip: skipQuery,
        onCompleted(data){
            fetchItineraryFromGoogle(data);
        },
        variables: {itineraryId}
    })
```

However this works:

```js
    const { data } = useQuery(GET_ITINERARY, {
        skip: true,
        onCompleted(data){
            fetchItineraryFromGoogle(data);
        },
        variables: {itineraryId}
    })
```

so does this:

```js
    const { data } = useQuery(GET_ITINERARY, {
        skip: 1==1,
        onCompleted(data){
            fetchItineraryFromGoogle(data);
        },
        variables: {itineraryId}
    })
```

so why doesn't my boolean constant work?

Comment: That would suggest that you're expression `props.match.params.itineraryId == placeState.itineraryId` is evaluating as `false` at least some of the time, even if it eventually evaluates as `true`. It would only take it equaling `false` during a single render to trigger the query.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure why you feel the need this logic in your component. If the component unmounts and then remounts, the hook will be called again but the data itself will be populated from the cache, not another request to the server.

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks for your reply :) mostly because i don't want fetchItineraryFromGoogle to run again when the itineraryId has not changed. For now it does :/

Comment: Ah. There might be a better way to handle that. You could use `useEffect` instead, for example. Alternatively, `fetchItineraryFromGoogle` could keep track of what itineraries it has already fetched and return early if it's called twice for the same one. Better yet, depending on your business case, you might be able to use local state and local resolvers if you're integrating data from both your GraphQL server and another API.

Comment: good shout! thank you, @DanielRearden, i'll restructure my code to that :)